# Is there any syntax or command in php to check whether a number is in a set of numbers?

Tags: php, set, comparison, range

I come from another language, so I miss this feature on php. For example, if I want to check whether if a number is 2, 4, between 7 to 10, or 15, I would like to express it as:

```
if ($x in [2, 4, 7...10, 15]) { do_something(); }
```

Instead of:

```
if ($x == 2 || $x == 4 || ($x >= 7 && $x <= 10) || $x == 15) { do_something(); }
```

Or:

```
switch ($x) {
case 2:
case 4:
case 7:
case 8:
case 9:
case 10:
case 15:
    do_something();
    break;
}
```

Or even:

```
switch (true) {
case ($x == 2):
case ($x == 4):
case ($x >= 7 && $x <= 10):
case ($x == 15):
    do_something();
    break;
}
```

Is there any way in php to do that or workaround similar to that? I use this comparison a lot in my code, and the "in set" format makes my code much more readable and less error-prone (writing `7...10` is safer than writing `x >= 7 && x <= 10`). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very much possible to specify the range. Use [range()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function here.

> **range** - Create an array containing a range of elements

```
$values = range(7, 10); // All values from 7 to 10 i.e 7, 8, 9, 10
$values = array_merge($values, [2, 4, 15]); // Merge your other values

if (in_array(3, $values)) { 
    /* Statements */
}
```

Comment: Well, I suppose I can insert range into the `array_merge (range[7, 10], [2, 4, 15))` that's a very useful information. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You may use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) for this:

```
if (in_array(3, [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15])) { 
    do_something(); //true, so will do
}
```

Comment: Oooh, that's awesome! Yeah, this looks a better form that I can use, even though it still lacks number range. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want check either value exist or not you can use `in_array()`

If you want to check position of value than you can use `array_search()`

```
$arr = array(1,2,3); 
var_dump(in_array(3, $arr)); // return true 

var_dump(array_search(3, $arr)); // return 2
```

Comment: That's another great feature that's good to know! Usually I do a loop for that. Thanks!